# MKMapview freezes when zoomEnabled=NO and call setRegion (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone

I am a beginner in iPhone development and I have come across a problem with `MKMapView`. First let my describe how to reproduce the problem.

1. Create a view-based application
2. In Interface Builder, add a MapView that cover the whole view area
3. Add a `UIButton` over the Mapview (size 50x50 is fine, put it in a corner)
4. Associate the MapView in IB with a MapView reference in the code
5. Associate the `UIButton` to an handling method (touch down).

Here's the code for the controller (MapTest3ViewController.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapTest3ViewController : UIViewController {
MKMapView *myMapView;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *myMapView;
- (IBAction) zoomClicked:(id)sender;
@end
```

(MapTest3ViewController.m)

```
#import "MapTest3ViewController.h"

@implementation MapTest3ViewController

@synthesize myMapView; 

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
//myMapView.zoomEnabled = NO; 
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction) zoomClicked:(id)sender
{
// when zoom button is clicked, zoom on a specific region
CLLocationCoordinate2D locationCoordinate2D;
locationCoordinate2D.latitude = 35.6994;
locationCoordinate2D.longitude = 139.78;
MKCoordinateSpan coordinateSpan;
coordinateSpan.latitudeDelta = 1;
coordinateSpan.longitudeDelta = 1;
MKCoordinateRegion coordinateRegion;
coordinateRegion.center = locationCoordinate2D;
coordinateRegion.span = coordinateSpan;

[myMapView setRegion:coordinateRegion animated:YES];

}

@end
```

I have set scrollEnabled=YES, zoomEnabled=YES and showUserLocation=YES in IB. The application WORKS fine. I can zoom using pinching, I can scroll, whenever I push the "Zoom" button the view area moves to the region defined in zoomClicked.

**The problem**

When I set `zoomEnabled=NO` in `viewDidLoad`, I can no longer zoom using pinching gestures which is fine. However, if I "play" with the map, scrolling, trying to zoom(which of course doesn't work), then push the zoom button the map freezes and I can no longer scroll or do anything.

Again, how to replicate the problem (`zoomEnabled=NO`)

1. After application loads, the map of the entire earth appears. Do some pinching gestures in and out, scroll the map. (Zoom doesn't work which is expected)
2. Push the zoom button which should set the map the a specific region (in the code Tokyo, Japan) -> the map freezes.

**My setup**

iPhone OS 4.0.1/iPhone 3GS/XCode 3.2.3 64bit/Testing done on the phone itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.